# Why i am getting "fd must not be null" validation error on adding sticker pack to WhatsApp?

Tags: android, whatsapp, whatsapi, whatsapp-stickers

I am creating an android application for adding custom stickers to WhatsApp. I have followed [this example](https://github.com/WhatsApp/stickers) but on adding sticker to WhatsApp an error dialog is displayed with message ***"There is some problem with this sticker pack and it cant be added to Whatsap"***. The validation error i get onActivity result is ***"fd must not be null"***. I am unable to find the cause of this error. What is FD in this case?

**What i have tried:**
-I tried adding publisherEmail,website etc all fields but still getting this error.

-For tray image i have added a webp icon in my assets folder and provided its name in trayImageFile field.

**What is required:**
-The custom sticker pack i am fetching from firebase should be added to WhatsApp both normal and animated.

This is the json file which is created from my project

```
[
  {
    "androidPlayStoreLink":"i have added valid playstore link here removed purposely here",
    "animatedStickerPack":false,
    "avoidCache":false,
    "identifier":"50016",
    "imageDataVersion":"",
    "index":"0",
    "isCustom":false,
    "isPremimmum":false,
    "isWhitelisted":false,
    "licenseAgreementWebsite":"",
    "name":"Thanks",
    "privacyPolicyWebsite":"",
    "publisher":"TEST CONTENT",
    "publisherEmail":"1",
    "publisherWebsite":"",
    "stickerMode":0,
    "stickers":[
      {
        "emojis":[

        ],
        "imageFileName":"500161",
        "size":0,
        "uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.example.myapppackagename/files/50016/500161.webp"
      },
      {
        "emojis":[

        ],
        "imageFileName":"500162",
        "size":0,
        "uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.example.myapppackagename/files/50016/500162.webp"
      },
      {
        "emojis":[

        ],
        "imageFileName":"500163",
        "size":0,
        "uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.example.myapppackagename/files/50016/500163.webp"
      },
      {
        "emojis":[

        ],
        "imageFileName":"500164",
        "size":0,
        "uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.example.myapppackagename/files/50016/500164.webp"
      },
      {
        "emojis":[

        ],
        "imageFileName":"500165",
        "size":0,
        "uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.example.myapppackagename/files/50016/500165.webp"
      },
      {
        "emojis":[

        ],
        "imageFileName":"500166",
        "size":0,
        "uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.example.myapppackagename/files/50016/500166.webp"
      },
      {
        "emojis":[

        ],
        "imageFileName":"500167",
        "size":0,
        "uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.example.myapppackagename/files/50016/500167.webp"
      },
      {
        "emojis":[

        ],
        "imageFileName":"500168",
        "size":0,
        "uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.example.myapppackagename/files/50016/500168.webp"
      },
      {
        "emojis":[

        ],
        "imageFileName":"500169",
        "size":0,
        "uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.example.myapppackagename/files/50016/500169.webp"
      },
      {
        "emojis":[

        ],
        "imageFileName":"5001610",
        "size":0,
        "uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.example.myapppackagename/files/50016/5001610.webp"
      },
      {
        "emojis":[

        ],
        "imageFileName":"5001611",
        "size":0,
        "uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.example.myapppackagename/files/50016/5001611.webp"
      },
      {
        "emojis":[

        ],
        "imageFileName":"5001612",
        "size":0,
        "uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.example.myapppackagename/files/50016/5001612.webp"
      },
      {
        "emojis":[

        ],
        "imageFileName":"5001613",
        "size":0,
        "uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.example.myapppackagename/files/50016/5001613.webp"
      },
      {
        "emojis":[

        ],
        "imageFileName":"5001614",
        "size":0,
        "uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.example.myapppackagename/files/50016/5001614.webp"
      },
      {
        "emojis":[

        ],
        "imageFileName":"5001615",
        "size":0,
        "uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.example.myapppackagename/files/50016/5001615.webp"
      },
      {
        "emojis":[

        ],
        "imageFileName":"5001616",
        "size":0,
        "uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.example.myapppackagename/files/50016/5001616.webp"
      },
      {
        "emojis":[

        ],
        "imageFileName":"5001617",
        "size":0,
        "uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.example.myapppackagename/files/50016/5001617.webp"
      },
      {
        "emojis":[

        ],
        "imageFileName":"5001618",
        "size":0,
        "uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.example.myapppackagename/files/50016/5001618.webp"
      },
      {
        "emojis":[

        ],
        "imageFileName":"5001619",
        "size":0,
        "uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.example.myapppackagename/files/50016/5001619.webp"
      },
      {
        "emojis":[

        ],
        "imageFileName":"5001620",
        "size":0,
        "uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.example.myapppackagename/files/50016/5001620.webp"
      },
      {
        "emojis":[

        ],
        "imageFileName":"5001621",
        "size":0,
        "uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.example.myapppackagename/files/50016/5001621.webp"
      },
      {
        "emojis":[

        ],
        "imageFileName":"5001622",
        "size":0,
        "uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.example.myapppackagename/files/50016/5001622.webp"
      },
      {
        "emojis":[

        ],
        "imageFileName":"5001623",
        "size":0,
        "uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.example.myapppackagename/files/50016/5001623.webp"
      },
      {
        "emojis":[

        ],
        "imageFileName":"5001624",
        "size":0,
        "uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.example.myapppackagename/files/50016/5001624.webp"
      },
      {
        "emojis":[

        ],
        "imageFileName":"5001625",
        "size":0,
        "uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.example.myapppackagename/files/50016/5001625.webp"
      },
      {
        "emojis":[

        ],
        "imageFileName":"5001626",
        "size":0,
        "uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.example.myapppackagename/files/50016/5001626.webp"
      },
      {
        "emojis":[

        ],
        "imageFileName":"5001627",
        "size":0,
        "uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.example.myapppackagename/files/50016/5001627.webp"
      },
      {
        "emojis":[

        ],
        "imageFileName":"5001628",
        "size":0,
        "uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.example.myapppackagename/files/50016/5001628.webp"
      },
      {
        "emojis":[

        ],
        "imageFileName":"5001629",
        "size":0,
        "uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.example.myapppackagename/files/50016/5001629.webp"
      },
      {
        "emojis":[

        ],
        "imageFileName":"5001630",
        "size":0,
        "uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.example.myapppackagename/files/50016/5001630.webp"
      }
    ],
    "stickersAddedIndex":30,
    "totalSize":0,
    "trayImageFile":"my_tray_icon.webp"
  },
  {
    "androidPlayStoreLink":"i have added valid playstore link here removed purposely here",
    "animatedStickerPack":true,
    "avoidCache":false,
    "identifier":"60006",
    "imageDataVersion":"",
    "index":"0",
    "isCustom":false,
    "isPremimmum":false,
    "isWhitelisted":false,
    "licenseAgreementWebsite":"",
    "name":"Dogs",
    "privacyPolicyWebsite":"",
    "publisher":"TEST CONTENT",
    "publisherEmail":"1",
    "publisherWebsite":"",
    "stickerMode":0,
    "stickers":[
      {
        "emojis":[

        ],
        "imageFileName":"600061",
        "size":0,
        "uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.example.myapppackagename/files/60006/600061.webp"
      },
      {
        "emojis":[

        ],
        "imageFileName":"600062",
        "size":0,
        "uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.example.myapppackagename/files/60006/600062.webp"
      },
      {
        "emojis":[

        ],
        "imageFileName":"600063",
        "size":0,
        "uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.example.myapppackagename/files/60006/600063.webp"
      },
      {
        "emojis":[

        ],
        "imageFileName":"600065",
        "size":0,
        "uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.example.myapppackagename/files/60006/600065.webp"
      },
      {
        "emojis":[

        ],
        "imageFileName":"600066",
        "size":0,
        "uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.example.myapppackagename/files/60006/600066.webp"
      },
      {
        "emojis":[

        ],
        "imageFileName":"600067",
        "size":0,
        "uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.example.myapppackagename/files/60006/600067.webp"
      },
      {
        "emojis":[

        ],
        "imageFileName":"600068",
        "size":0,
        "uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.example.myapppackagename/files/60006/600068.webp"
      },
      {
        "emojis":[

        ],
        "imageFileName":"600069",
        "size":0,
        "uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.example.myapppackagename/files/60006/600069.webp"
      },
      {
        "emojis":[

        ],
        "imageFileName":"6000610",
        "size":0,
        "uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.example.myapppackagename/files/60006/6000610.webp"
      },
      {
        "emojis":[

        ],
        "imageFileName":"6000611",
        "size":0,
        "uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.example.myapppackagename/files/60006/6000611.webp"
      },
      {
        "emojis":[

        ],
        "imageFileName":"6000612",
        "size":0,
        "uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.example.myapppackagename/files/60006/6000612.webp"
      },
      {
        "emojis":[

        ],
        "imageFileName":"6000613",
        "size":0,
        "uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.example.myapppackagename/files/60006/6000613.webp"
      },
      {
        "emojis":[

        ],
        "imageFileName":"6000614",
        "size":0,
        "uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.example.myapppackagename/files/60006/6000614.webp"
      },
      {
        "emojis":[

        ],
        "imageFileName":"6000615",
        "size":0,
        "uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.example.myapppackagename/files/60006/6000615.webp"
      },
      {
        "emojis":[

        ],
        "imageFileName":"6000616",
        "size":0,
        "uri":"file:///data/user/0/com.example.myapppackagename/files/60006/6000616.webp"
      }
    ],
    "stickersAddedIndex":15,
    "totalSize":0,
    "trayImageFile":"my_tray_icon.webp"
  }
]
```

Is there something i am missing here? Which field should be added here for fd? Can somebody please help me out with this. Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

if you have custom uri then do this

```
File file =new File(uri);
                Uri newUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(newUri,"r" );
```

and in content provider class in openAssetFile

```
 pfd = Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()).getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(
                                csp.getTrayImageUri(), "r");
```

then perform your work moreover if you have any query IB me or comment here

Answer (score 0):

The only reason is that you haven't provided Read/Write permission in your android app.
Add permission logic in code and reinstall app -> give permission and it works!